# Fake rewriting with PHP and NGINX

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx

A few year ago, I made a script which can false rewrite my page - written in PHP - by using the 404 error and a redirection.

With this system, I could rewrite my page without touching Apache - except via htaccess. My system wasn't secure at all, but that was not the point at this time.

I was using this :

**.htaccess**

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?redirect
```

and this

**index.php**

```
if(isset($_GET['redirect']))
    {
        if (preg_match("#"."([0-9-]+)-([^0-9](?:.+))#isU", $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'], $redirect)) 
        {
            header("Status: 200 OK", false, 200);
            $redirect=abs($redirect[1]);
        }
        else header('Location: '.HOME_PAGE.'-E404.html');
    }
```

My question is: Is it possible to fake rewrite like before, but also with NGINX ? Because I can't with that.

My aim is to make my script portable. Noone needs to change NGINX config or APACHE config. And also making a rewriting script in order to clean URL.

Thanks ;)

Comment: Don't want to be rude but I think you need to do some homework first. And next, security is rule #1 when exposing some kind of server on the web. If you don't protect it, it is an easy prey for spreading bad software. Better safe than sorry.

Comment: Haha, thanks for the advise. Like I said, my aim is not to give my script or use it. It's purely to know if it's possible or not. That's why I said "I don't care about security".

Because, I guess there is a way - without high security - to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You could try nginx `try_files` directive in this way:

```
# Inside some server config
location / {
    try_files $uri /404.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include         fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass    unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

Here I also use fastcgi to connect to php-fpm server.